# How do 1-d compact submanifolds look like?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I was wondering whether it is true that every 1-d compact submanifold $\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ that is $C^1$ is a closed curve that is also $C^1$, cause I cannot think of more examples.

Therefore, I would be very interested in a proof of this theorem. So, if you have an internet reference or know how to show this, then I would like to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Since compact one-dimensional manifolds are disjoint unions of $S^1$s, you are right at least for connected submanifolds.

Comment: and if they are not connected?

Comment: @Lipschitz, it is a union of circles.

Comment: so the answer is no, because you can just take two circles right?

Comment: @Lipschitz, the answer for what?

Comment: the answer to my question. I asked: Is every compact $C^1$ manifold representable by a closed curve?

Comment: @Lipschitz, Igor has answered your question. If the manifold is connected then it is a circle. If it is not connected then, it is a union of disjoint circles.

Comment: @Lipschitz, I had assumed in my previous comment that the manifold do not have boundary. If the manifold has boundary then, if it is connected, you have a closed interval, on the other hand, if it is not connected then, you have union of closed intervals.

Comment: @Tomás he did say "compact manifold", which generally means closed, but the OP might not be completely up on the jargon, you are right.

Comment: sorry, I am confused, what do you (Tomás) mean by "have boundary"? @IgorRivin I would appreciate it, if you would edit your post and talk about the not-connected case, since you obviously know the answer, then I can accept it.